# if i want to go to a specific result in a different sheet in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

My issue is that i want a way to move directly to a specific entry in a different sheet,

I will try to explain it:

I have in sheet1 a column B with several results, 
in sheet2 i have a cell E5 with a drop list that brings results from column B in sheet1, 
and i chose for example B2, 
so now E5 from sheet2 equals B2 in sheet1.

What i want is that when i select E5 in sheet2,  it directly jumps to the original cell B2 in sheet1.

Is that possible somehow?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Super User. What have you tried so far? What method did you use to create the drop down?

Answer (score 2):

In short, **Yes** it is possible.
In my case I have created two Sheets that is '*Sheet1*' and '*Sheet2*. And suppose I want to be refered/ switched to cell B3 of '*Sheet1*' whenever I click on the cell A3 of '*Sheet2*'. And also I want the same/ fetch value of cell B3 of '*Sheet1*' to cell A3 of '*Sheet2*'.
To accomplish so follow the steps below:

**Step 1:** First of all you need to have data in *Sheet1* and *Sheet2* (or whatever the name of the Sheet you have).

**Step 2:** To have the same/ fetch value in *Sheet2* cell A3 of *Sheet1* cell B3 use the formula
`=('Sheet_name'!Cell_name)` in cell A3 of *Sheet2*, in this case it will be `=('Sheet1'!B3)`.

[image: Fetching Data]

**Step 3:** Now go-to the cell of *Sheet1* where you want to be refered, (in my case it is B3 of *Sheet1*) select the cell and *Right click* on it. In the right click context menu click on "**Define Name**" and in the pop-up window give a name to the cell in the '*Name field*' (in my case the cell is B3 and I am naming it as B3_abc) and click on "**OK**".

[image: Defining Cell Name]

**Step 4:** Now go-to the cell of *Sheet2* from where you want to be refered (in my case it is A3 of *Sheet2*), select the cell and *Right click* on it in the right click context menu click on "**Hyperlink**".
In the new pop-up window, in the '*Link to:*' section in left-side click on "**Place in This Document**" option and select the name of the cell of *Sheet1* from '*Defined Names*' section you have defined in Step 3 (in my case it is B3_abc) and click on "**OK**".

[image: Refering Cell]

**Step 5:** Now whenever you will click on cell A3 of *Sheet2* you will be refered to cell B3 of *Sheet1*. And also any change in the cell B3 of *Sheet1* will be reflected back in the cell A3 of *Sheet2*.

**Done!**